# Question Regarding finding the mean and variance of a MGF function?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, standard-deviation, moment-generating-functions

This question confused me at the end where it says a normal random variable. A breakdown of the answer would be great

The Question states:

The MGF for the (general) normal distribution is given by Mx(t) = exp(μt + (σ^2)(t^2)/2). Use this to find the mean and variance of a normal random Variable

Answer (score 0):

If you go over your course material again you will find that the n-th moment of a random variable is the n-th derivative of its moment generating function at point t=0.

Comment: I know that but what is meant here when it says that "...of a NORMAL random variable? What is meant by Normal? Also you sound like my Prof

Comment: A normal random variable would mean a random variable which follows the normal distribution. And FYI I've been working as a TA for a long time.

Comment: Ok I think I know how to find the Mean. I'd simply have to substitute 0 since the first MGF is the mean. But I still don't understand how I would find the variance

Comment: Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2